Dividing data to show in separate rows in thymeleaf
I am trying to generate a table in thymeleaf with data coming from a springboot backend.summaryList is List objects where SummaryDTO has aliquotID,ic50,fold,refID,ic50_ref attributes.
My requirement is in my table I need to show data as two rows under headers Name,IC50,Fold.So refid values comes under name header and ic50_ref value comes under Fold under.I tried below code but getting org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'aliquotID' cannot be found on null.Please suggest how to fix this.
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>IC50</th>
                        <th>Fold</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(summaryList)}">
                        <td colspan="9">no data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <p>List Size: [[${summaryList.size()}]]</p>
                    <tr th:each="dto: ${summaryList}">
                        <tr>
                            <td th:text="${dto.aliquotID}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${dto.ic50}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${dto.fold}"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td th:text="${dto.refID}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${dto.ic50_ref}"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>


The error you've given is saying you have null elements in your ${summaryList}... if ${summaryList} contains a null element (rather than a SummaryDTO as you claim, then you will get the error message you have given).
As for the table itself, it should look like this:
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>IC50</th>
            <th>Fold</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(summaryList)}"><td colspan="9">no data</td></tr>
        <p>List Size: [[${summaryList.size()}]]</p>
        <th:block th:each="dto: ${summaryList}">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${dto.aliquotID}"></td>
                <td th:text="${dto.ic50}"></td>
                <td th:text="${dto.fold}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${dto.refID}"></td>
                <td th:text="${dto.ic50_ref}"></td>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </tbody>
</table>

Using th:block instead of tr will give you valid HTML (except for the p tag...) and not nested trs.
